# Why is adding a column to an already-created table considered bad practice?

Tags: php, mysql

I was looking at the ALTER procedure to add a column to an already-created table and a lot of the answers specified that adding columns dynamically wasn't considered good practice. 

 I am trying to create an extra column to monitor the attendance on a particular day so in relation to that aim, is altering the table still bad practice, because I can't really see a way around it?

Comment: It means you mix different aspects of your implementation. It opens a whole bundle of security risks. Only consider that you'd have the permission to your application to modify the database definition. There are good reasons why one wants to keep the permission footprint of a productive application as small as possible. What if you have a bug in your application that allows to do _any_ modifications?

Comment: Depends upon your specific requirements, It's not really that bad of a thing

Comment: Consider what will happen if you have multiple users accessing that table... Plus, if you dynamically keep adding columns to a table, you'll end up adding a huge number of columns, which will make the table unusable

Comment: Consider accepting Lieven's excellent answer.

Answer (score 8):

It's not something that should be done willy-nilly and it requires planning but if you have changing requirements or simply forgot something, by all means: add the column.

**Never adding a column is simply no good advice and not realistic. You should be able to**

- Adapt to changing requirements
   *Requirements only stop changing when the application is discontinued or the bussiness is bankrupt*
- Keep your database normalised
   *Instead of adding a column you could decide to add an entire table referencing your existing table avoid the alledged bad practice. Please don't.*
- Fix mistakes in the specification/implementation
  *we're all human*

**but keep in mind that adding a column**

- requires testing
- can easily break existing applications
- requires testing
- requires planning
- and requires testing

Answer (score 1):

There's too ways to understand your question,

1. you're talking about adding a column to an already-existing table, but you're not exactly doing it dynamically, on the fly from your application, but rather once when you update your application code. during deployment. This is ok as long as you keep your application and db structure in sync.
2. you're talking about adding a column from your app, runtime, whenever some condition happens or data is in a state that would require adding a table. This is rarely a good thing to do. It might be ok in a CMS in some cases where you're creating content types that are not expected to change and are added rarely. However, mostly it's an indication of bad design and will cause both performance and complexity issues.

Comment: I am trying to create an extra column to monitor the attendance on a particular day so in relation to that aim, is altering the table still bad practice, because I can't really see a way around it?

Comment: Is that column specific to that one day or is it actually covering all the special scenarios for all "special days" or special conditions, like a reference key to another table detailing the special condition? If former, it is bad practice. If the latter, it sounds ok.

Answer (score 1):

It depends when do you want to make these changes.

If the changes happen during because of extended features of a system, they are IMHO ok.

But if the changes are done continuously while using the application, that is bad design.

In general, you make a distinction between

1. Data Description Language (DDL) where you make changes in the layout. These are mainly `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` and alike. These changes should not be done during the normal run of the application, only during setup.
2. Data Manipulation and Query Language (DML) where you operate on the data in a DB. This is what an aplication normally does: `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Database should be created in the very begining of project and it should stay as it is. When you create your query, for example INSERT and you don't use named colummns it can crush your system.

For EXAMPLE

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES('a','b','c');
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO `table`(column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c',...)
```

There are a lot of lines of code than can crash. Mostly those that are based on columns numbers instead of their names. Changing DB can create a lot of problems and if the system is pretty big they can be hard to be found.

It's better practice to create relations within tables than creating a lot of columns.

Morever you should read about **Database normalization** which "is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency."

Comment: Much as your arguments make sense, I'd like to hear of a live, and used system in which the database has never had to have tables altered - to say that "Database should be created...and...stay as it is", is just not realistic.

Comment: It is realistic, If you change DB you should rewrite project. If you have good MVC structure then you look only at models but sometimes it may be really hard. I have a lot of projects where DB remained as it was designed. It needs you to use very good db design tool, good specification, testing, feedback etc. It can be done.

Comment: Never had requirements change in those projects then? I question whether you're working with real clients :P And yes, the code would have to change with the database changes, that goes without saying.

Comment: @Robert: you probably never designed real system if you are so sure that it is possible to get away without changing something as you evolve. It is not

Comment: Actually I have 8 years experience in designing real system. Of course there are changes but before customer wants the application there is the specification where every requirment is written just to avoid such changes in the phase of designing db. If you predict that something may change you design it to make it as easy to change as possible. For example adding "col1", "col2" and when the users needs another collumn "col3" is senseless.